# Sum only first few values of the list using Java8

Tags: java, list, java-8

Here is the list from which I need to add only first 3 elements instead of adding complete list. How can I achieve this using java 8?

```
  List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3);
    int sum = list.stream().sorted().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Comment: 3 first before or after sorting the list?

Comment: It should be mentioned, however, that [`limit(...)` can be quite expensive, especially on large, sorted `Stream`s and large limit-values](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long)). I would advice to [`sort(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) the list first, then construct a [`subList(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)), and then sum over this `subList`.

Comment: you can explore IntStream as well. you just need to limit the range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `limit()` as shown below

```
int sum = list.stream().sorted().limit(3).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also explore 'IntStream.range' as an alternate or such kind of operations. Only drawback is that you have feed a sorted array.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3).stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(IntStream.range(0,3).map(i -> list.get(i)).sum());
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel ! updated the description!